# CodeIgniter's insert_id() function is always returning 1

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have the following:

```
function insert_data($table=0,$data)
    {
        if($table !== 0)
        {
            if ($this->db->table_exists($table))
            {
                $this->db->insert($table,$data);
                return $this->db->insert_id();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I call it using

```
...
$insert_info = array(
    'event_id'      =>$id,
    'checklist_name'=>$_POST['event_name'].' Checklist',
    'checklist_type'=>2,
    'status'        =>1,
    'created_by'    =>$this->session->userdata('superadmin_id'),
    'created_date'  =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'updated_by'    =>$this->session->userdata('superadmin_id'),
    'updated_date'  =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
$new_checklist_id = $this->db->insert('checklist_event',$insert_info);
echo $new_checklist_id;
die();
...
```

However, 1 is always echo'd. I can confirm there are a dozen or so records in the table so unsure why it's returning 1 each time. Any suggestions?

This is the structure of the table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, 1 is always echo'd

you actually echo'ing out the return of the [Query Builder Class insert() function](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert#CI_DB_query_builder::insert), which is either true or false.

use this approach:

```
$this->db->insert('checklist_event',$insert_info);
$new_checklist_id = $this->db->insert_id();
echo $new_checklist_id; die();
```

You seem not to be calling the function insert_data($table=0,$data) at all